# "Value cannot be null" error in Powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am using the script below to export the CRM solution:

```
$crids=Get-Credential DOMAIN\GOPI
$conn=Get-CrmConnection -ServerUrl "http://XXXXXXXXXX/DeployPOC" -Credential 
Export-CrmSolution -conn $conn -SolutionName "Remove_Shipping_Address" -SolutionFilePath "C:\Users\Gopi\OneDrive\MYRD\DeploymentAutomation\CRM" -SolutionZipFileName MySolution.zip -TargetVersion 'gopi'
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
Export-CrmSolution : System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "WriteAllBytes" with "2" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: bytes" ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: bytes
at System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(String path, Byte[] bytes)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object , Object )
-- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
At line:16 char:1
+ Export-CrmSolution -conn $conn -SolutionName "Remove_Shipping_Addres ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Export-CrmSolution
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Where are you using the `$crids` variable? Should it come after the `-Credential` parameter? I'd also recommend changing `-SolutionZipFileName MySolution.zip` to `-SolutionZipFileName .\MySolution.zip` and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Sorry for the typo (Copi past) PFB for the script


$crids=Get-Credential Domain\gopi
$conn=Get-CrmConnection -ServerUrl "http://XXXXXXXXX/" -OrganizationName "DeployPOC" -Credential $crids
Export-CrmSolution -conn $conn -SolutionName "Remove_Shipping_Address" -SolutionFilePath "C:\MYRD\DeploymentAutomation\CRM" -SolutionZipFileName MySolution.zip -TargetVersion 'gopi'

Comment: i am still getting the same error